# Model parameter Description in XMLCOMMENTS

Tags: xml-documentation, swashbuckle

I am using [Swashbuckle 5.5.3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Swashbuckle.Core/) and customized API documentation by using [XMLComments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-api/app-service-api-dotnet-swashbuckle-customize). I have put description of model properties which is not edited in API documentation.

Sample Code:

```
/// <summary>
/// SomeDetails.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="Model">SomeDetails.</param>
/// <param name="Model.UserName">SomeDetails of username.</param>
/// <param name="Model.OwnerId">SomeDetails.</param>
```

[image]

It shows summary, which I put on top, but does not show model property details.

Comment: What are params of your action? On screenshot i see two params: userName and ownerId and i don't see any "Model" object you  describe.

Comment: MethodName([FromUri(Name = "")] ModelName model)
That is why you don't see model.

Comment: If you are using the model object as the input, then the description will be taken from the documentation provided in the properties (like UserName, OwnerId etc.) of the ModelName class

Answer (score 2):

As stated in [SwashBuckle documentation](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle#including-xml-comments), you have to put your parameter description on **properties** themselves, not as params on methods.

In your case this means having a model like this:

```cs
public class Model
{
    /// <summary>
    /// user Name (e.g. ...)
    /// </summary>
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Id of the owner in context of...
    /// </summary>
    public int OwnerId { get; set; }
}
```